# Java: Storing bits in the most memory efficient manner

Tags: java, huffman-code, storing-data

I have written an algorithm to implement Huffman Coding for compressing text files. It basically takes in a string as an input and generates a string of bits as output. However, I am having trouble storing this binary data as it is being stored as a string where each bit is a character and consumes 2 bytes of memory for storage. End result, output file is larger than the input, making the whole program worthless. How should I store this binary output such that each bit takes only one bit of memory for storage?
ps. I have tried using a BitSet but that did not change the size of the output at all

Comment: Store your data in a byte array.

Comment: As the comment above suggest, use a byte[] which you can write to a File with the FileOutputStream

Comment: tried it, didn't work. I guess its because each bit is stored as a byte but I might be wrong. The goal is to make the output much smaller than the input

Comment: The problem is the intermediate step, don't store them in a string at all. Just dump them into a byte[] (or BitSet)

Answer (score 1):

Once you have your result in the `BitSet`, you can call

`BitSet.toByteArray()` to save your data to a file, i.e.:

```
FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File(...), bitSet.toByteArray());
```

And `BitSet.valueOf(byte[])` to read your data from file:

```
BitSet bitSet = new BitSet(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File(...)));
```